# как в пайтоне использовать в программе данные, которые дает пользователь?

Tags: python, данные

Пишу программу, в которой пользователь задумывет какое-то слово. Программа справишает сколько букв в слове, затем предлагает буквы. Если программа угадывает букву, то спрашивает какая она по счету в слове. И так пока не выведет придуманное пользователем слово. Как можно расставить буквы "по местам" ? Прилагаю часть кода. Совсем новичок

```
alphabet = []
number = []
player_letters = []
current_round = 0

# FUNCTIONS

def creat_alphabet():

alphabet = ["а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "е", "ё", "ж", "з", "и", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с", "т", "у", "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ", "ъ", "ы", "ь", "э", "ю", "я"]
return alphabet

def shuffle_alphabet(alphabet):
import random
random.shuffle(alphabet) # this will shuffle the list

def deal_letters(alphabet, n):
letters = alphabet[:n] # get the top 1 letters from the alpabet
for letter in letters:
    alphabet.remove(letter) # delete each of those cards from the alphabet

return letters

def get_yes_or_no():
comp_letters = deal_letters(alphabet, 1)
while True:
    answer = input("В вашем слове есть буква ", comp_letters, "?").lower()
    if answer == "да":
        return True
    elif answer == "нет":
        return False
    else:
        print("Это не буква. Введите букву.")

def lenght_of_the_word():

while True:
    answer = input("Сколько букв в вашем слове?")
    if answer == int():
        return True
    else:
        print("Это не число. Попробуйте еще раз")

def number_letter():
while True:
    answer = input("Какая по счету буква ", comp_letters, " в слове?")
    if answer == int():
        return True
    else:
        print("Это не число. Попробуйте еще раз")

def check_word(word):
word = list("")
lenght = lenght_of_the_word()
yes_no = get_yes_or_no()
num = number_letter()
if yes_no in range(lenght):
    word = yes_no[:num]
```

здесь непонятно что делать

```
# MAINLINE
# This is where you will implement the code to play the game

print("Добро пожаловать в игру Угадай слово")

run True
while run:
print("--------------------------")
comp_win = False

# each round creat and shuffle a new alphabet
alphabet = creat_alphabet()
shuffle_alphabet(alphabet)
current_round += 1

print("Раунд", current_round)
```

Comment: по каким "местам"?  Слово - это по сути список. У списка есть индексы. Это и есть "места".

Comment: я заранее не знаю какие мне индексы нужно использовать, так как это зависит от задуманного пользователем слова. Как в этом случае установить диапазон длины слова и приравнять букву к месту в слове?

Comment: а заранее и не надо знать, ведь пользователь их потом вводит. Так и приравнять - число, которое ввел пользователь - это индекс

Comment: def get_yes_or_no():
    comp_letters = deal_letters(alphabet, 1)
    while True:
        answer = input("В вашем слове есть буква ", comp_letters, "?").lower()
        if answer == "да":
            return True
        elif answer == "нет":
            return False
        else:
            print("Это не буква. Введите букву.")

Comment: def lenght_of_the_word():
    '''
    Gets number letters of the player's word.
    :return: bool
    '''
    while True:
        answer = input("Сколько букв в вашем слове?")
        if answer == int():
            return True
        else:
            print("Это не число. Попробуйте еще раз")

Comment: def number_letter():
    while True:
        answer = input("Какая по счету буква ", comp_letters, " в слове?")
        if answer == int():
            return True
        else:
            print("Это не число. Попробуйте еще раз")

Comment: я построила 3 диалога, но не знаю как теперь использовать данные, которые даст пользователь

Comment: У вас очень странные проверки, попробуйте сначала с ними разобраться. И весь код должен быть в вопросе, в комментариях нормально читаются только короткие фрагменты кода.

Comment: `lst = list("слово")` - вот слово превратилось в список букв, к которому можно обращаться по индексам, брать буквы, менять буквы.

Comment: Вот это ``if answer == int():`` - ерунда. Проверку на число делают не так, к тому же вам такая проверка совсем не нужна.

Comment: Отступы почините, сейчас у вас всё плохо с ними